# GCC-PHAT on MATLAB (still challenging)

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft, cross-correlation

I am trying to compute time delay estimation between two acoustic signals using GCC-PHAT on MATLAB. However, it is still challenging to code GCC-PHAT with fft/ifft, where time delay estimation is always zero. I have spent hours googling but have not been successful yet. My code is demonstrated on a simple example with two sinusoidal waves as follows.

```
Fs = 8000;
dt = 1/Fs;
f1 = 100;
tdelay = 0.002; 
t3 = (0:dt:(1)-dt)';
x = cos(2*pi*f1*t3);
y = cos(2*pi*f1*(t3-tdelay));

n=2*length(x)-1;
N=2^nextpow2(n);

xfft = fft(x,N);
yfft = fft(y,N);

df=Fs/N; 
sampleIndex = -N/2:N/2-1; 
f=sampleIndex*df; 

R=xfft.*conj(yfft);
c=R./abs(R);
ic=fftshift(ifft(c));
figure; plot(f,ic)
[~,ind]=max(abs(ic));
lagDiff=f(ind);                      
timeDiff=lagDiff/Fs;
```

I understand that the GCC-PHAT can be coded by R, and it works as stated in this post https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31956/gcc-phat-generalized-cross-correlation-matlab

However, the R code is not robust, where it fails in some occasions. For instance, for the code in the link aforesaid the results are wrong at `f=100Hz` and `tdelay=0.01` or at `f=50Hz` and `tdelay=0.01`.

Can anyone who has successfully solved GCC-PHAT on Matlab or known the gccphat(), a licensed function, explain more detailed about this issue? I have seen many posts concerned about this seemingly easy problem, but it is still unsolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and Matlab's gccphat() differs on the extraction of the phase. While you've implemented the general approach, to divide by the magnitude, they computes the exponential of the angle. Avoiding therefore numerical issues related with the division by 0 in:

c=R./abs(R);

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constant factor to the weighting function to avoid amplifying the error when the denominator is small，like that c=c./(abs(R)+a);a can be a constant

Comment: sorry it should be c=R./(abs(R)+a)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's new Phased Array Toolbox allows you to use [GCCPHAT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/gccphat.html) function on your signals.

```
timeDelay = gccphat([Y1(span),Y2(span),Y3(span),Y4(span),Y5(span),Y6(span),Y7(span)],Y0(span),FS);
```

timeDelay variable will have 7 values with respect to the sampling frequency FS.